# How find where this code located in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

When I made a one site, I've found a one digital when complete the order and can't locate it in sources. Usually I just search necessary phrase\sentence or word, but I can't find it by search "1".

How I can find where it's located?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried searching for `echo` and `print`? You probably echo a function return value or something else where the return value is not just a static `1`.

Comment: You can't find it by "1" because it's in the database, maybe you should take a look there, and try to figure out wich query calls that value and search for that piece of code ?!

Answer (score 0):

it should be in virtuemart component, but without knowing your html i only can guess

Comment: Thanks for reply.. In fact Joomla have a lot of echo or print and i can't locate it by this.. It much strong, because it haven't any html near this "1", it just "1" and nobody else. It's don't appear on other pages, only at finish order page. I saw into "order_done.php". This file have all what this page write, but excluding "1". I don't know how to find it...

Answer (score 0):

I would search:
1. the template
2. the articles
3. the modules/plugins
4. good luck